# Reindex Pandas dataframe based on date and value of a column

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe,

```
ID  StationID  Date         ParamName  ParamValue
0   A          1990-01-08   metal      0.5
1   A          1990-01-08   wood       1.4
2   A          1990-01-08   glass      9.7
3   B          1990-01-08   metal      0.8
4   B          1990-01-08   wood       4.8
5   C          1990-01-08   metal      0.6
6   A          1990-02-03   metal      0.5
7   A          1990-03-01   metal      1.2
8   B          1990-03-01   metal      0.9
9   C          1990-03-01   metal      1.1
```

How would you reindex the ID column of the dataframe to increment only when the `date` or `StationID` are different. How can the above dataframe be reindexed to the dataframe below (assume the date contains datetime objects)?

```
ID  StationID  Date         ParamName  ParamValue
0   A          1990-01-08   metal      0.5
0   A          1990-01-08   wood       1.4
0   A          1990-01-08   glass      9.7
1   B          1990-01-08   metal      0.8
1   B          1990-01-08   wood       4.8
2   C          1990-01-08   metal      0.6
3   A          1990-02-03   metal      0.5
4   A          1990-03-01   metal      1.2
5   B          1990-03-01   metal      0.9
6   C          1990-03-01   metal      1.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
df.assign(ID=(df.StationID!=df.StationID.shift()).cumsum()-1)
Out[151]: 
   ID StationID        Date ParamName  ParamValue
0   0         A  1990-01-08     metal         0.5
1   0         A  1990-01-08      wood         1.4
2   0         A  1990-01-08     glass         9.7
3   1         B  1990-01-08     metal         0.8
4   1         B  1990-01-08      wood         4.8
5   2         C  1990-01-08     metal         0.6
6   3         A  1990-02-03     metal         0.5
7   3         A  1990-02-03      wood         1.2
8   4         B  1990-02-03     metal         0.9
9   5         C  1990-02-03     metal         1.1
```

Update :-)

```
df['ID']=df.StationID+df.Date.astype(str)
df.assign(ID=(df.ID!=df.ID.shift()).cumsum()-1)
Out[163]: 
   ID StationID        Date ParamName  ParamValue
0   0         A  1990-01-08     metal         0.5
1   0         A  1990-01-08      wood         1.4
2   0         A  1990-01-08     glass         9.7
3   1         B  1990-01-08     metal         0.8
4   1         B  1990-01-08      wood         4.8
5   2         C  1990-01-08     metal         0.6
6   3         A  1990-02-03     metal         0.5
7   4         A  1990-03-01     metal         1.2
8   5         B  1990-03-01     metal         0.9
9   6         C  1990-03-01     metal         1.1
```

Comment: Think Char said they need it to change based on StationID OR Date